# jQuery : increase slice value based on condition

Tags: jquery

I am working on a chat application, there is an anchor tag to show previous comments. By clicking on this anchor tag I am showing last 10 hidden div with class **hidePrevComments** (this class has style display none).

The scenario is that top most div with class hidePrevComments (to be shown on anchor's click) should have another class **mt-10**, if class **mt-10** is missing 
number of div to be shown will increase by 1 every-time. So the total div to be shown will be 11. If again this happen total div to be shown will be 12 and so on. Sorry if question is not clear. TIA.

**jQuery function :-**

```
function showPrevComments() {
        $('#divMessage').find('div.hidePrevComments').slice(-10).removeClass('hidePrevComments');
    }
```

**HTML:-**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showPrevComments();" class="bluetext chat-link" style="display:none;">View previous comments</a>
```

Comment: so what's not working ?

Comment: So what is the question? What is not working?

Comment: i think there should be some loop to check "mt-10" and increment slice value..

Comment: increment in negative way, can say decreament..